# Is it safe to delete SFDevCluster folder

Tags: sharepoint-server

We have on premise SharePoint 2019 platform and installed service fabric and service bus 1.1 with TLS support, in other words workflow manager CU5.
But in some point it was installed Microsoft SDK and SFDevCluster folder which has large trace logs. Is it safe to delete that folder?

Answer (score 0):

> 1) - Remember that the Service Fabric platform is running on the same
>   nodes as your services (in this case your local machine). We have a
>   bunch of system services and are exchanging regular messages in order
>   to maintain the cluster, monitor the health of the cluster and your
>   services etc. So even if your services aren't doing much the system as
>   a whole may still be. Since we maintain logs for diagnostic purposes,
>   this can cause the build up you've seen. By default we only keep a few
>   days worth of logs, but if this is still too  much it's configurable
>   in the cluster manifest that gets created. Check out C:\Program
>   Files\Microsoft SDKs\Service Fabric\ClusterSetup\NonSecure. I've
>   bolded the sections you're looking for in the snippet below:
>
> 2) Cleaning out the logs is simple - use the Local Cluster Manager to
>   "Reset" the cluster. This deletes all the logs and sets the cluster
>   back to the initial state.
>
> 3) You can use the settings I specified above to reduce the total
>   amount of space the logs take up. There's also one file (the shared
>   state log) which currently starts at 8Gb and whose size is not
>   configurable today. We'll be fixing that in the future. Personally I
>   haven't touched any of the things above, I just don't leave the
>   cluster running when I'm not using it, and that's generally worked for
>   me.

[Source](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/e501b9cf-e750-48c5-b342-4cd3bc19c5fc/sfdevcluster-directory-getting-huge?forum=AzureServiceFabric)

For more information, kindly have a look at the below MRL's

1. https://sahebg.github.io/computersceince/how-to-change-azure-service-fabric-replicator-log-size-drive/
2. https://github.com/Azure/service-fabric-issues/issues/138

Comment: Hello Karthik, we do not have created folder C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Service Fabric\ClusterSetup it is empty. We assume that installation was not successful on a SharePoint server. Local Cluster Manager app is also not available. In SFDevCluster\Log\Traces are generating each day logs, so the Traces folder is about 3GB. Cluster is not active.